# Silverlight in an IFrame in IE

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0

I am having a problem with calling a silverlight 4 app from an iframe.  I have a page (see below) that calls a separate program that contains a silverlight application.  This seems to work fine on some computers but on other computers it ends up with a blank screen.  I have tried setting explicit widths on the iframe as well as verifying that the src of the iframe is valid.  This seems to happen on in Internet Explorer both versions 7 and 8.  It seems random which computers it works on and which it doesn't.  Any ideas?

Code of the iframe page:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<iframe runat="server" id="mainframe" style="height: 600px; width:1024px; min-height:600px; min-width:1024px; border:0;" frameborder="0"  src="http://XX.XX.XX.XX/silverlightapp/TestPage.html" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably security related. It looks like the web page you are embedding is from another domain. Depending on the security settings on the machine, Silverlight content may be blocked within the iframe.

Comment: Any idea what setting it may be?

Comment: I am not really sure. In my experience it is best to just avoid these things and come up with something else that is not blocked by security settings. But having said that, I would try adding both domains to the "Trusted Sites" zone in IE and see if that helps.

Comment: I just used a response.redirect instead of an iframe.

Comment: Yes, if you can do that it is a much better solution.